# FFMPEG Batch Copy Metadata from "Folder1File1.mp3" to "Folder2File1.mp3" in different folders

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, metadata, file-transfer, transfer

I have two separate files in separate folders with the same name and I would like to transfer the metadata from the file in "folder1" to "folder2". 
Then I would like to add a whole bunch of files fitting this same format and batch transfer all of the metadata information.

From a stack exchange thread I've tried:

```
"The following script will loop through the the files in one directory, find corresponding files in a second directory and then combine these two files into a third output directory

dir1=FIRST DIRECTORY
dir2=SECOND DIRECTORY
output=OUTPUT DIRECTORY
for file in $(ls $dir1); do
  ffmpeg -i "$dir1/$file" -i "$dir2/$file" -map 1 -c copy \
   # copies all global metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv  
   -map_metadata 0 \
   # copies video stream metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv
   -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v \
   # copies audio stream metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv
   -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a \
   "$outdir/$file"
done"
```

But for the life of me I cannot get this to work properly and it is a bit overkill. He continues on saying:

```
If you want to make something reuseable you could put this in a script with the following header (remove the assignment for dir1, dir2 and output in the script above). And then call it as script.sh dir1 dir2 outdir

#!/bin/bash
set -x errexit # exit immediately on error
dir1="$1"
dir2="$2"
output="$3"
```

And I am totally lost. Can someone please help me to get this to work and walk me through it a bit easier as I'm fairly inexperienced with code/FFMPEG.

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain the relationship of your question with [`batch-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info)?

Comment: *"I cannot get this to work properly"*. What's the actual issue? Are there any errors? Is the problem with the scripting or with the ffmpeg command? Does the ffmpeg command even get executed? What is your OS? (This was previously tagged with batch-file, so I want to confirm that you're not trying to run a bash script in Windows cmd.)

Comment: Thank you, but I found an easier way to do this using Foobar2000. Help no longer needed.